# Microphone based-input CLASH, using microphone to jump, whilst also using microphone to record and play-back audio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, game-development, microphone

The first script **(JumpFromMicrophone)** I have created is a script where based on my MICROPHONE audio input, the game object (player) moves up on the Y axis. The game object also automatically moves forward using speed on the Z axis.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class JumpFromMicrophone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource source;
    public AudioLoudnessDetection detector;
    public Vector3 minPosition;
    public Vector3 maxPosition;
    public float speed = 2;

    public float loudnessSensibility = 100;
    public float threshold = 0.1f;

    // The duration of the smooth transition
    public float smoothTime = 0.1f;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float loudness = detector.GetLoudnessFromMicrophone() * loudnessSensibility;

        if (loudness < threshold)
            loudness = 0;
        else
            loudness = (loudness - threshold) / (1 - threshold);

        // Calculate the target position, keeping the current X and Z values
        Vector3 targetPosition = Vector3.Lerp(minPosition, maxPosition, loudness);
        targetPosition.x = transform.localPosition.x;
        targetPosition.z = transform.localPosition.z;

        // Smoothly move the object towards the target position
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.localPosition, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    // reloads the scene if obstacle hits player
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
        }
    }

}
```

The second script **(RNP)** created records this audio picked up by the MICROPHONE and then plays it back to the player using a recording from a generated AudioSource. This is done using MaxRecordingTime, which I am fine using as I am going to relate it to timed game audio once this issue has been resolved.

```
public class RNP : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The AudioClip that will be recorded
    public AudioClip recordedClip;

    // The maximum recording time in seconds
    public int maxRecordingTime = 10;

    void Start()
    {

        // Start the recording and playback coroutine
        StartCoroutine(RecordAndPlayback());
    }

    IEnumerator RecordAndPlayback()
    {
        // Start recording from the default microphone
        recordedClip = Microphone.Start(null, true, maxRecordingTime, 44100);

        // Wait for the specified number of seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(maxRecordingTime);

        // Stop the recording
        Microphone.End(null);

        // Create an AudioSource to play the recorded audio
        AudioSource audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.clip = recordedClip;
        audioSource.loop = false;
        audioSource.Play();

        // Wait for the audio to finish playing
        yield return new WaitWhile(() => audioSource.isPlaying);

        // Destroy the AudioSource
        Destroy(audioSource);
    }
}
```

However, the second script seems to clash with the first and implementing the second script does not allow for some aspects of the first script to work, I am beginning to think it might be something to do with the use of the Microphone for both scripts clashing, but I have no idea how to solve this issue so that both work together without disabling one another.

The **JumpOnMicrophone** script does not allow the player to move up the Y axis when the **RNP** script is added as a compenent onto the game object (player), but the player still moves along the Z axis.

Some fixes I have attemped that did not work:

- Placing the 2nd script on another GameObject rather than the player
- Combining both scripts

If anyone could help me figure this out, it would be greatly appreciated.

*** **EDIT** ***

**AudioLoudnessDetection** script

```
public class AudioLoudnessDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int sampleWindow = 64;
    private AudioClip microphoneClip;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        MicrophoneToAudioClip();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
    }

    public void MicrophoneToAudioClip()
    {
        string microphoneName = Microphone.devices[0];
        microphoneClip = Microphone.Start(microphoneName, true, 20, AudioSettings.outputSampleRate);
    }

    public float GetLoudnessFromMicrophone()
    {
        return GetLoudnessFromAudioClip(Microphone.GetPosition(Microphone.devices[0]), microphoneClip);
    }

    public float GetLoudnessFromAudioClip(int clipPosition,AudioClip clip)
    {
        int startPosition = clipPosition - sampleWindow;

        if (startPosition < 0)
            return 0;

        float[] waveData = new float[sampleWindow];
        clip.GetData(waveData, startPosition);

        // compute loudness
        float totalLoudness = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleWindow; i++)
        {
            totalLoudness += Mathf.Abs(waveData[i]);
        }

        return totalLoudness/ sampleWindow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue probably is more related to `AudioLoudnessDetection` .. what is this doing?

Comment: This calls one of the other scripts made, it basically detects how loud the audio is using the audioclip which is the microphone recording in real time. I will include (edit) the code in my original post for referencing.